# Sort the table in sequential conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `users` table with 5 columns, `id`, `age`, `is_premium`, `is_male`, `is_customer` where `id` is the primary key.

First statement I do is. This statement has the potential of returning 0 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE is_premium = 1 AND
is_name = 0 AND
is_customer = 0
```

Then ONLY from the rows I got from the above query, I want to find the person with the largest age.

```
SELECT * FROM <from the above query>
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(ID) <from the above query>)
```

**Question:** How do make these 2 separate SQL statements into a single statement and what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key column called `id`, just move the query in a sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE is_premium = 1 AND is_name = 0 AND is_customer = 0
    ORDER BY age DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: I do not want to use `ORDER BY`. `MAX()` seems more efficient

Comment: _seems more efficient_? People normally benchmark the queries to determine if they are slow or fast.

Comment: if many users have same `age`, the `id` selected is random.. better add `id ASC` in your `ORDER BY` after `age DESC`

Comment: Yes... but the more appropriate solution would be to ask OP how they want to handle ties. I mean why should user #10 aged 40 be preferred over user #9 aged 40?

Comment: @Jackie keep in mind when two or more poeple have the same max age within this selection, MySQL could return a different record on every run .. As this `ORDER BY age DESC` feels like to be non deterministic ("random") for equal values pretty sure that age column does not has unique values.. You need to define what you want to do with the ties meaning using `ORDER BY age DESC, id ASC/DESC` that would make it 100% deterministic (fixed) on every run assuming id to have a `PRIMARY/UNIQUE` key making it unique data..

Answer (score 2):

why not directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE is_premium = 1 
AND is_name = 0 
AND is_customer = 0
ORDER BY age DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

for mysql version 8 and above you can also use common table expressions (CTE):

```
WITH D AS (
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE is_premium = 1 
    AND is_name = 0 
    AND is_customer = 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM D
WHERE AGE = (SELECT MAX(AGE) FROM D)
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Jackie . . . The first solution is the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you will have multiple users with same `max()` age

```
select * from users t1
inner join (
    select max(age) maxage from users
    where is_premium=1 and is_name=0 and is_customer=0) t2
on t2.maxage = t1.age
where is_premium=1 and is_name=0 and is_customer=0
```

**or** if you don't want to repeat your `conditions`.

```
select * from users t1
inner join(
    select  
        (select max(t.age) from users t where t.id = t2.id) as maxage,
        t2.id
    from users t2 
    where is_premium=1 and is_name=0 and is_customer=0) t3 on t3.id = t1.id
```